# how to use Azure kakaTrigger wih On-Prem Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, azure-functions

Is it possible to have HTTPtrigger for a java azure function that can be triggered by a message from a topic? Please note, that our kafka servers(broker, zookeeper,...) are not Azure cloud. if yes, how can we set the configuration parameters to be able to consume topic?

Comment: Well, what happens when you give the trigger your on prem bootstrap server?

Comment: I am very new to the azure function but based on my experience with Kafka, I need to set some parameters(eg. `ssl.keystore.location`) to be able to consume the message in topic. while I was going to use [KafkaTrigger Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.kafkatrigger?view=azure-java-legacy) I don't know how to setup this parameters.

Comment: That's a Java property, not for librdkafka configuration that Azure uses. You can see the methods listed in the docs there that correspond to the ssl properties that can be set